# Count JSON objects

Tags: php, json

I have the following php code to return some values from a JSON formated feed.

```
$json = file_get_contents("//URL HERE");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data['users'] as $item)
{
  print $item['userName'];
  print ': ';
  print $item['status'];
  print ' - location: ';
  print $item['location']['y'];
  print ' / ';
  print $item['location']['x'];
  print '<br>';
}
```

This code returns me the name of the user with the status and it's location.
At the end of the users I want to count them.

the feed has the following format:

```
{
 "startTime":"time",
 "users":
 [
 {
  "location": {
    "y": 47.61,
    "x": 21.52
  },
  "status": 48,
  "userName": "testuser",
},
{
  "location": {
    "y": 48.01,
    "x": 20.88
  },
  "status": 49,
  "userName": "testuser18",
}
],
  "startTime1": 1314,
  "endTime1": "141414"
}
```

I've tried to use the following code:

```
$iCount = count($data);  //returns value 4
$iCount1 = count($item); //returns value 3
print $iCount;
```

But I need to count how many users are. Basically to count how many times "users" object appears in the feed.

Comment: Try `count($data['users'])`

Comment: http://php.net/count - http://php.net/arrays - -1 from me because question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = file_get_contents("//URL HERE");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo count($data['users']);
```